# Angular mat-table wasn't displaying data, fixed but not sure why the fix works

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I was trying to display simple data retreived from a local API that I store in an array using `mat-table` to no avail. I managed to fix it but I'm new to Angular/Typescript/Programming in general and I have no idea why my fix worked, could someone help me understand why it did?

**pago.component.ts (before fix)**

```
  export class PagosComponent implements OnInit {
      facturasElectricas: FacturaE[] = [];
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['fecha', 'monto'];
      ...
      ngOnInit() {
          this.getFacturasElectricas();
      }
      getFacturasElectricas(): void {
      const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.pagoService.getFacturasElectricas().subscribe(facturas => {
          facturas.forEach(f => {
              if (f.factura.contrato === id && !f.factura.pagado) {
                  this.facturasElectricas.push(f);
              }
          });
       });
      }
   }
```

**pago.component.ts (after fix)**

```
   export class PagosComponent implements OnInit {
          facturasElectricas: FacturaE[];
          displayedColumns: string[] = ['fecha', 'monto'];
          ...
          ngOnInit() {
              this.getFacturasElectricas();
          }
          getFacturasElectricas(): void {
          const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
          this.pagoService.getFacturasElectricas().subscribe(facturas => {
              this.facturasElectricas = [];
              facturas.forEach(f => {
                  if (f.factura.contrato === id && !f.factura.pagado) {
                      this.facturasElectricas.push(f);
                  }
              });
           });
          }
       }
```

The only line I changed was `this.facturasElectricas = [];`, placing it inside the `getFacturasElectricas()` method.

Here's the html part
**pago.component.html**

```
<table *ngIf="facturasElectricas" mat-table #table [dataSource]="facturasElectricas">

            <ng-container matColumnDef="fecha">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.factura.fecha}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="monto">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Debe </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.monto}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

[Output before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3EW3.png)

[Output after fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebi8Z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I can think of is regarding Angular's changeDetectionStrategy.

- https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Please see link below for a comprehensive information on how changeDetectionStrategy works:

- https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Sample code with asynchronous data source (using setTimeOut())

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-not-updated

In my understanding **mat-table** has a **OnPush** changeDetectionStrategy as seen in material repo in github:

- https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table.ts

In short, since the dataSource array reference did not change **mat-table** has no reason to update the table rows and after the **"fix"**, by using `this.facturasElectricas = []`, you are assigning new array object to the property hence, **mat-table** is now notified that **dataSource** is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to material.angular.io tables API, rendering the rows `renderRows` works like that Renders rows based on the table's latest set of data

> If the table's data source is a DataSource or Observable, this will be
>   invoked automatically each time the provided Observable stream emits a
>   new data array. Otherwise if your data is an array, this function will
>   need to be called to render any changes.

for more check the table API page [TABLE API](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)